# Overflow in constant value computation error in C#

Tags: c#, overflow, variable-assignment

I need to assign constant value in integer (or other data type).

I got "Cannot convert ..." error with the assignment.

[image]

Casting doesn't seem to work with "Overflow ..." error.

[image]

What's wrong with this?

Comment: Hi, there! 0xffffffff is over the limit, use ulong and redefine the import function parameters if this is about PInvoke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined too many `F`s in the constant.  Using `0xFFFFFFFF` the compiler must choose a a storage location that supports a *positive* value of `0xFFFFFFFF`.  The max *positive* value of an  `Int32` is instead `0x7FFFFFFF` and hence the compiler correctly errors.  The only types which can hold `0xFFFFFFFF` are `uint` or one of the 64 bit storages.

To fix this just use `Int32.MaxValue`

```
int i32 = Int32.MaxValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

The maximum number a 32 bit int can represent is 0x7fffffff. The 7 at the front occurs rather than another f is because int is *signed*, so the top bit represents the sign (positive or negative) of the number.

In your first example the compiler sees a number that can only be represented by an unsigned int, so it assumes it is a UInt32. This cannot be converted to an int, hence the error.

I'm your second example you are forcing the conversion with a cast, but the number won't fit into an int, so an overflow (number too big) occurs.